# How to use "star" (symbol) in hyperlink

Tags: support, hyperlinks, special-characters

How to encode the star (`*`) in a hyperlink. For example, this link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA*

points to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA, not the correct one. How to append the star at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to URL encode any strange characters - so for your case append `%2A` to your URL

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA%2A)

Comment: The asterisk [being hexadecimal 2A](http://www.asciitable.com/).